# Wait for a socket message to be received?

Tags: asynchronous-processing, socket

Let's say I have a socket server set up on my system, and connect to it in **Mathematica 11.3** via

```
mysock = SocketConnect["X.X.X.X:YYYYY"];
```

where `X` are ip numbers, and `Y` are port numbers. This properly establishes a connection, so that I can send a message to the server via

```
WriteString[mysock, "Hello World!"];
```

and successfully receive it on the server side.

However, what if I want to have Mathematica run through a loop that sends data to the server and then blocks the loop until the server sends a confirmation message for a received package? I looked at the documentation, but could not find a socket function that would block the loop until a server message comes in. How can I do this in Mathematica?

Comment: [`SocketListen`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SocketListen.html)?

Comment: @flinty As far as I can tell, this function is not blocking. Maybe I am missing something?

Comment: To block there is SocketWaitAll[{mysock}] - there is an example in the documentation https://wolfram.com/xid/0bc5rxf2ms43gn4-69sahc but reverse client and server. For your case it should proceed only after the ack and the socket becomes ready again.

Comment: @flinty Your SocketWaitAll suggestion (or, alternatively, SocketWaitNext) solved my problem. If you post it as an answer, I will upvote and accept.